# query to obtain final status as fail or absent when any one of listed subject is failed or absent in hive

Tags: mysql, database, hive, db2

```
 select * from college;
    btech   cse     dbms    fail
    btech   cse     java    absent
    btech   cse     unix    pass
    btech   ece     edc     pass
    btech   ece     power   pass
    btech   ece     embeded pass
    mba     marketing       mlaw    pass
    mba     marketing       mtheory fail
    mba     hr      hrtheory1        pass
    mba     hr      hrtheory2        absent
```

Output should be like this :-

```
btech cse fail
btech ece pass
mba  marketing fail
mba hr hrtheory absent
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM college WHERE column4 != 'pass'` OR `SELECT * FROM college WHERE column4 IN ('fail', 'absent')`

Comment: The last line of the desired result is different from all the others

Comment: Can you please share the table's structure (specially name and column names) so we a common set of names to use in answers?

Comment: btech cse has both 'fail' and 'absent', so why does 'fail' take priority?

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed your last result is `mba hr absent`, and I add some names for your column. Try following, may help for you;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5fc9/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE college
    (`name` varchar(5), `major` varchar(9), `class` varchar(9), `result` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO college
    (`name`, `major`, `class`, `result`)
VALUES
    ('btech', 'cse', 'dbms', 'fail'),
    ('btech', 'cse', 'java', 'absent'),
    ('btech', 'cse', 'unix', 'pass'),
    ('btech', 'ece', 'edc', 'pass'),
    ('btech', 'ece', 'power', 'pass'),
    ('btech', 'ece', 'embeded', 'pass'),
    ('mba', 'marketing', 'mlaw', 'pass'),
    ('mba', 'marketing', 'mtheory', 'fail'),
    ('mba', 'hr', 'hrtheory1', 'pass'),
    ('mba', 'hr', 'hrtheory2', 'absent')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
 name, major,
 case 
 when find_in_set('fail', group_concat(result)) > 0 then 'fail'
 when find_in_set('fail', group_concat(result)) = 0
      and find_in_set('absent', group_concat(result)) = 0
      and find_in_set('pass', group_concat(result)) > 0 then 'pass'
 when find_in_set('fail', group_concat(result)) = 0
      and find_in_set('absent', group_concat(result)) > 0
      and find_in_set('pass', group_concat(result)) > 0 then 'absent' end as result
from college
group by name, major
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5fc9/3/0)**:

```
|  name |     major | result |
|-------|-----------|--------|
| btech |       cse |   fail |
| btech |       ece |   pass |
|   mba |        hr | absent |
|   mba | marketing |   fail |
```

In Hive, may like this;)

```
select
 name, major,
 case 
 when ARRAY_CONTAINS('fail', collect_set(result)) then 'fail'
 when ARRAY_CONTAINS('fail', collect_set(result))
      and ARRAY_CONTAINS('absent', collect_set(result))
      and ARRAY_CONTAINS('pass', collect_set(result)) then 'pass'
 when ARRAY_CONTAINS('fail', collect_set(result))
      and ARRAY_CONTAINS('absent', collect_set(result))
      and ARRAY_CONTAINS('pass', collect_set(result)) then 'absent' end as result
from college
group by name, major
```

Comment: hi reno thanks for your reply, your query works in mysql but I need it in hive

Comment: There's quite a lot of query here.

Comment: @Akhil And in hive, maybe you can replace `group_concat` to `collect_set`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with final status, but you can get the output you described with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM college WHERE col4 = 'fail' OR col4 = 'absent';
```

If you don't have more variables than 'fail', 'absent', 'pass', you can just use

```
SELECT * FROM college WHERE col4 <> 'pass';
```

Comment: hi let me explain with a simple exmple suppose a student has 6 subjects if he fails in any one subject then his final_status  of exam is failed ryt...? Same procedure follows here.

Comment: Sounds like you have another table named 'students' that you'd like to JOIN and see the results per student? Correct me if I'm wrong. What are you trying to acccomplish exactly?